# How to display actual URL with Selenium-IDE

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-ide, geckodriver

(I'm French  so sorry for my language...)
I want to ***download PDFs*** in some sites with *Selenium*

I've already tried with the *web-driver* alternative but I need to go in approximately 500 urls using ***Firefox***... So using *selenium IDE* is way faster and more practical.
So... I'm on the good page and click on the pdf's url and it opens in another tab. I want to get the url of the other tab.

Here a part of the TEST.side file within the selenium-IDE code

```
     "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "57a28847-d129-4cd1-b1f2-7ce91fcc0f71",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=.rows-container:nth-child(5) .CS-icon-pdf",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "487d74b6-a424-4166-88a4-dc111ae6b17d",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["ec447b0b-b9b3-445f-88bf-fee0abbfcb4f"]
  }],
  "urls": ["some url"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

I really didn't find any solutions that work

So... I'm on the wanted page and click on the pdf's url and it opens in another tab. I want to get the url of the other tab.

I know there's someone, somewhere, who can help me.

So thanks to you random citizen !

Edit:

Here the html [source](https://www.institutionnels.bnpparibas-am.fr/institutionnels-institutionnels/fundsheet/produits-de-taux/parvest-sustainable-bond-euro-corporate-i-c-lu0265317569/).
I'm looking for the ***Rapport annuel*** pdf in the ***Documents*** section

Comment: Is the url of the pdf (in `href` for example) different from the one in the opened tab ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel No it isn't
I got the same url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `store attribute` to retrieve the `href`attribute.
Here is an example using an xpath :

[image: Selenium IDE store attribute command]

And the documentation of the command:

> store attribute attribute locator, variable name
>   Gets the value of an element attribute. The value of the attribute may differ across browsers (this is the case for the "style" attribute, for example).
>
> arguments:
>   attribute locator - An element locator followed by an @ sign and then the name of the attribute, e.g. "foo@bar".
>   variable name - The name of a variable without brackets.

Comment: In this case, I need to know earlier the url, isn't it ?

Comment: You need to know where it is, `myPdfLink` is the id of the element:  `<a id="myPdfLink" href="theUnknowURL" />`

Comment: I have many others attributes with the same *id* and the same *class*..
I already tried to check the class and id of the attribute but i got only the first *href* encountered

Comment: With the same id ? That's badly incorrect, it's supposed to be unique. Please add your html source to your question

Comment: Add the relevant html code please, not a link. And I'm talking about the html `id` attribute